# Am I calling my function correctly in main?

Tags: c, string, function, date, scanf

I was assigned an assignment to take the users Input as MM/DD/YY , after I get the input its suppose to print out if the date is valid or invalid. I am only allowed to use %s to get the users input not %d or else it would be a lot easier.

Am I calling my getInput function correctly? The program doesn't print out if the users input is valid or not and I can't figure out why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


//Declares function
void getInput(char *userInput1, char *userInput2, char *userInput3);
//Declares variables.
char userInput1, userInput2, userInput3;


int main(void) {
    char userInput[100];
    printf("Enter a date inthis format : MM/DD/YY :");
    scanf("%s", &userInput);
    char *userInput1 = strtok(userInput, "/" );
    char *userInput2 = strtok(NULL, "/");
    char *userInput3 = strtok(NULL, "z  ");
    getInput(userInput1, userInput2, userInput3);
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}

void getInput(char *userInput1,char *userInput2,char *userInput3)
{
// If user inputs a valid date this will run.
if (0 > userInput1<12, 0>userInput2<31, 0>userInput3 < 99) {
// If user month input is this...
switch (*userInput1){
//if User month input is 02 this will run
case 02:
//If user year is a leap year this will run
if (*userInput3 % 4 == 0) {
//If user day is inbetween 0-29 it will say the date is valid.
if (0 > *userInput2 > 29) {
printf("You entered a valid date, %s/%s/%s", *userInput1, *userInput2, *userInput3);
}
// If the day of the February isn't 0-29 it will print it is invalid.
else
printf("Invalid date.");
}
case 04:
//Their are only 30 days in April, if user Inputs 31 it is invalid.
if (*userInput2 == 31) {
printf("Invalid date.");
}
//Every other date should be valid because the main if else statement filters it all out.
else {
("You entered a valid date, %s/%s/%s", *userInput1, *userInput2, *userInput3);
}
case 06:
if (*userInput2 == 31) {
printf("Invalid date.");
}
//Every other date should be valid because the main if else statement filters it all out.
else {
("You entered a valid date, %s/%s/%s", *userInput1, *userInput2, *userInput3);
}
case 11:
if (*userInput2 == 31) {
printf("Invalid date.");
}
//Every other date should be valid because the main if else statement filters it all out.
else {
("You entered a valid date, %s/%s/%s", *userInput1, *userInput2, *userInput3);
}
break;
}
}
//If the user enters a date that isn't valid , Invalid date prints.
else {
printf("Invalid date.");
}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: In C you can't define a function inside of another function (including `main`). Also, `&userInput1` is the address of a single `char`, but `%s` is reading a string, in this case of 2 characters, so you're going to have a problem there. Why do you want to read the values as character strings?

Comment: Read the line using `fgets()`, then scan the buffer, something like use `if (3 == sscanf(buffer, "%d/%d/%d", ...`

Comment: @lurker , I'm only allowed to take the users Input as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Read the line as a string and then tokenize it with i.e `strtok` function.